# Autofac - Register plugins by type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, plugins, c#-4.0, autofac

I'm writing a plugin system: every plugin is in his own assembly that must be loaded by autofac and is signed by an attribute with a parameter that set the type of plugin. I would be able to resolve in my asp.net mvc app the plugins by type, how can I do this? Every plugin inhrerit by an abstract class and override predefinited methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RegisterAssemblyTypes()` is probably the starting point you're after:

```
Assembly[] assembliesWithPlugins = // find these somehow
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembliesWithPlugins)
    .AssignableTo<MyAbstractPluginType>()
    .WithMetadata(t => GetPluinTypeFromMyAttribute(t));
```

Once you've registered your plug-ins this way, Autofac's Metadata support will allow you to consume them (http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Metadata). I presume from some of your later questions that you're already heading down this path.

Good luck with it.
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) for this and use [Autofac's MEF integration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MefIntegration).

Comment: why would you use mef? i don't know if i'm wrong but could i use autofac metadata or maybe named/keyed feature?

Comment: Both are valid approaches - if your plug-ins will be written by third party developers then MEF supplies a .NET standard mechanism for defining them.

Comment: Sorry, my assumption was that the plugins would be 3rd party :)

Comment: yes the plugin will be written also by 3rd party developers and at the moment i define plugin info in an attribute

Answer (score 0):

Create a Autofac.Module in every plugin assembly. Register your plugin stuff there, and from your main application load your plugin dlls, look for Modules, register in container.
Then resolve and have fun ;).